# Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain Nodejs nodemailer express

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

So I'm doing this app in Node.js with express and I have this error
Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

```
at Error (native)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1092:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:610:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:440:38) code: 'ESOCKET', command: 'CONN' }
POST /contact/send - - ms - -
```

I have change the mail service and also disavaible my antivirus, I cant find the sokution online, and a little bit of help is good for everybody

Thank youu

Answer (score 59):

There is a good discussion about using Nodemailer with self-signed certificates in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/406). Specifically, [this post](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/406#issuecomment-83941225) can help get rid of the error message:

> If you know that the host does not have a valid certificate you can allow it in the transport settings with `tls.rejectUnauthorized` option:
>
> `var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
>       host: "outmail.abc.co.th", // hostname
>       secure: false, // use SSL
>       port: 25, // port for secure SMTP
>       auth: {
>           user: "username@abc.co.th",
>           pass: "passwordmail"
>       },
>       tls: {
>           rejectUnauthorized: false
>       }
>   }));`

However, if you believe the mail services you are trying to use have valid certificates, you might have a local issue with your machine or network.

Comment: OP, you should accept this as the answer, this clearly works

Comment: @ty2k, any ideas if there are some security concerns using this?

I have problems when the nodemailer is sending emails locally, but on the server, there is no issue with the certificates. Additionally, I have started to see this error after reinstalling my machine, but I am pretty sure that I have never configured a certificate before for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
email: {
    smtp: {
        host: SMTP_HOST,
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        requireTLS: false,
        auth: {
            user: SMTP_USERNAME,
            pass: SMTP_PASSWORD,
        },
    },
    from: EMAIL_FROM,
}
```