# Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain with nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js

so i am working on a project with someone i am using nodemailer to send emails when user wants to reset password it works fine for me but when the person working with me tries it we face this error

Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Comment: Have you seen this question?: [Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain Nodejs nodemailer express](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46742402)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain Nodejs nodemailer express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46742402/error-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain-nodejs-nodemailer-express)