# Error: self signed certificate NodeMailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp, ssl-certificate, nodemailer

im trying to send an email with nodemailer but i get this error

> ```
> > Error: self signed certificate
> >     at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1515:34)
> >     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
> >     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:937:8)
> >     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:709:12) {   code: 'ESOCKET',   command: 'CONN' }
> ```

This is my code

```js
async function sendEmail({ from, to, subject, html }) {
  try {
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: mailer.host,
      port: mailer.port,
      secure: false,      
      tls: {
    ciphers: 'SSLv3',
        rejectUnauthorized: mailer.tls
      },
    });

    const info = await transporter.sendMail({ from, to, subject, html });

    console.log(info);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

someone can help me please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46742402/error-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain-nodejs-nodemailer-express

Comment: thank u for the awnser, im already read it, but does not the same problem, also the issue is diferent my error code is 'esocket'